# Wiring an outside outlet

Tags: wiring

I have Cedar Siding and would like to tap into a inside outlet and put a outside outlet on the siding.. Can I use a plastic old box and but in siding or do I need to use a metal box and have it on the outside of siding? Yes I know it has to be sealed..

Answer (score 2):

Sealed in this case is weatherproof, save your sanity and use something like this:

http://www.homedepot.com/p/Taymac-1-Gang-Horizontal-or-Vertical-Mount-Weatherproof-While-in-Use-Cover-Kit-MKG410C/202284520?N=5yc1vZca29

But feel free to recess it into your house.

Comment: You can't recess it too far, though, or you won't be able to operate the cover. Well, you mean to go ahead and recess the box itself to where the front mounting surface of the box is flush with the siding. Then the cover would basically screw on flush with the siding and protrude appropriately.  ;-)

Comment: I honestly love semantics games, sadly I am only sufficiently fluent in English to play well. Having said that, you mean that I can not operate the cover, if I only size the recess such that the cover will not operate in the recess. Clearly limiting the size of the recess will place constraints on the device inserted into the recess. I for instance do not place doors in walls, such that the door is unable to operate. The installation of a door is typically predicated on there being a use for a door when installed in its intended location. :P